# How to use JAXB to add a custom "type" attribute to my XML?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

this is a jaxb problem
one bean class

```
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @XmlType(name = "tableBean") 
  public class TableBean {
  @XmlAttribute
  private String type;

  @XmlElement(name = "created_at")
  private Date created_at;

  @XmlElement(name = "database_id")
  private int database_id;

  @XmlElement(name = "id")
  private int id;
```

i want xml like this

```
<tables>
  <table>
     <created_at type="datetime">2013-08-28T21:14:35+09:00</created_at>
     <database_id type="integer">1</database_id>
     <id type="integer">1</id>
 <table>
<tables>
```

i have try to make a class like this

```
public class Type_Int {

private String type;
private int id;
@XmlAttribute
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
@XmlValue
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

use@XmlAttribute in Type_Int.class i can get i want,but my project have many Variables,i could write classes for everyone,so wheather i can do somthing in my main bean.class,and i can make it easily

Comment: First, do you really need a type attribute? You have the type in your class so deserialisation is not a problem. Second, you only have to create one class per type then re-use those in your beans.

Comment: hi,TedTrippin,i konw what you say second,i had try and it really work.But,as i had said ,i have many not only two members in the class,so if i created them all,i thought it may waste time.so i want to find a better way,do you have any suggest?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map a field like:

```
private int id;
```

To an XML element like the following:

```
<id type="integer">123</id>
```

Then you could leverage an `XmlAdapter`.  Leveraging the `Type_Int` class from your question you could do create a class with the following declaration and then implement the required `marshal` and `unmarshal` methods to convert `Integer` to/from `Type_Int`.

```
public class IntAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Type_Int, Integer> {
    ...
}
```

To leverage this adapter you will need to change your field from the primitive type `int` to the object type `Integer` and annotate it as:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntAdapter.class)
private Integer id;
```